# Synonym for a "manther"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

I'm looking for a word or brief phrase that means someone who dates/pursues/has relationships with women much younger than himself.  If the word happens to be gender neutral (not specific to a particular gender) that's fine, but doesn't need to be.

While "manther" (a recent mutation on the word "cougar") is a lovely modern word, I cannot use it because I need a word that would fit in a historical/non-modern context. (Old, no longer commonly used words are fine).  Additionally I'm planning on using it in an insult, so if the word is vulgar or slang that is fine so long as it isn't modern slang.

I've also heard the phrase, "cradle snatcher", but I don't think this quite fits.

Comment: There's always "lech", short for [lecher](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lecher).  Doesn't necessarily imply a younger "target", but that's the usual assumption.

Comment: @HotLicks correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that just means they're looser with their sexual pursuits, plus it has the additional connotation of being willing to target anything old or young - nor does it imply the lecher is old.  (Though 'old lech', might work).

Comment: There are hundreds of synonyms; check a thesaurus.

Comment: @Mitch that are single words?  I can't seem to find any that aren't phrases.  I'll take a phrase if I have to, but I'm looking for a single word if possible.

Comment: There is, of course, the expression "robbing the cradle", but that tends to refer to the status after the relationship has been established.

Comment: It is hard to think of an old, gender neutral term.  Gender neutrality is in itself a modern concept. (Google's ngram viewer doesn't show any significant usage of the phrase until around 1976.) I expect that whatever you end up using will have an anachronistic air. If you are writing fiction, maybe make up something and let readers gather from context what you mean.

Comment: Since historically men tended to go for much younger women, there is probably no special word just for that. The older man in 'Lolita', Humbert Humbert, is probably the direction you're thinking of. Since 'manther' sounds made up, you might as well do the same.

Comment: @RichF It doesn't need to be gender neutral, I just don't mind if it is.

Comment: There is no single word as the patriarchy has never allowed it and only recently have women come into their own. a hundred years ago, women hardly worked outside the home, except on factory floors. Also, how the HELL could such a word be "gender neutral"?? Wait until the robots take over, then you'll get your gender neutral. I wonder if you have given any real thought to this. And what is this obsession with single words, anyway.

Comment: @Lambie I didn't specify such a word had to be gender neutral, just that I didn't mind if it happened to be.  eg: If there were a word which meant any individual who seeks out a significantly younger partner (regardless of gender), I'd take that.  I've looked through several thesaurus words before posting the question, when I could not find anything that quite matched.  No need to get rude about it.

Comment: @Leguestaurant Not rude, just plain spoken. I am not sure that thesauri are the way to go. Journals of sociology/anthropolgy/gender studies, more like it/

Comment: How much younger? There's [*parthenophile*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parthenophilia), or the gender neutral *pedophile*.

Comment: What is the historical period?

Comment: @1006a Pedophiles are adults attracted to children, not to younger men or women.

Comment: @Barmar Thus my question: *How much* younger? Some folks consider sixteen-year-olds to be "young women".

Comment: @1006a I don't think men who date 16-year-olds are usually considered pedophiles, it usually refers to people sexually attracted to pre-pubescent children.

Comment: @ab2 pseudo 1600s.  The question is dealing with adults, in general, but for the time period I don't think 16 would be considered unusual.  For purposes of the question consider a 50 year old dating an 18 year old, as an example.

Comment: If you're thinking very young women at a time when that was more socially acceptable, then parthenophile in its literal meaning fits pretty well. You might also play on the May-December cliche.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like @HotLicks answer is still the best given so far, though it was just a comment so I'm going to just go with that provided someone else doesn't come along with a better one:

"There's always 'lech', short for lecher. Doesn't necessarily imply a younger 'target', but that's the usual assumption."

Thanks for everyone else's input though, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If the man is elderly (not middle-aged), a common expression is **dirty old man**. From [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dirty%20old%20man):

> An elderly man that dreams of screwing women between the ages of 15-35, or women who look like they're 15-35. Often stare at their young flesh.

I'm not sure if this really fits your need, since the usual understanding is that he just leers at the young women, they never actually date, because the women find him creepy.

Comment: While its simple and does technically fit, I'd prefer a single word if possible.

Comment: If there were already a single word, *manther* probably wouldn't have been created.

Comment: The definitions at Urban Dictionary tend not to be of the highest quality. I suggest that you link to them but paraphrase and try to give a less tendentious definition.

Comment: @Mitch The first two sentences are consistent with my intuititive notion, so I've removed the rest of the definition, which are more subjective.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sugar_daddy):

> **sugar daddy** (plural sugar daddies) *noun*
>
> (slang) A man who spends money for the benefit of a relationship with an often younger romantic or sexual partner.
>
> *Usage notes:*
>
> This term typically implies that there is a romantic relationship between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Since 1964, (according to Barbara Kipfer & Robert Chapman, *Dictionary of American Slang*, fourth edition [2007]), younger women married by older men have sometimes been called **trophy wives**—especially when the man in question has become financially successful and decided that he has outgrown his "starter wife." It would make sense that such a man might be be called a **trophy hunter**—but I haven't seen that term widely used in that sense.

Similarly, men who are sexually aggressive or ardent womanizers are (again, according to Kipfer & Chapman) sometimes termed **wolves**, so it would make sense, if such a man consistently focused on much younger women, that he might be called a **big bad wolf**. That, at any rate, seems to be the sense of that phrase as used by [Sam the Sham](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNEYfIUDkh8).